# Why does renderToString throws error about useLayoutEffect while rendering Material-UI component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-leaflet

I am using React v.16.12.0 and @MaterialUI/core v4.8.1.

I am trying to create custom icon for React Leaflet Marker. The icon is a `Fab` component from Material-UI. To do that, I need to pass a HTML string to `L.DivIcon` [(DivIcon Docs)](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#divicon) Leaflet component, so I am using `renderToString()` method from `react-dom/server`.

And it is throwing an error:

> Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client.
>       in NoSsr
>       in button
>       in ForwardRef(ButtonBase)
>       in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
>       in ForwardRef(Fab)
>       in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Fab)) (at src/index.js:9)

While I'm not using useLayoutEffect.

Here's a simple example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';

function App() {
  return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Fab size="small" variant="extended">
      Test
    </Fab>);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Online: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-rendertostring-tc90b

Why is it throwing that error? What's incorrect with this code? Is there any other way to generate HTML-String from Material-UI Component in order to pass it as an icon to Leaflet Marker?

Comment: what happens if you save it to a variable on console.log it?    HERES A CODE SNIPPET:                


import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';

function App() {
  let test = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Fab size="small" variant="extended">
      Test
    </Fab>);

console.log(test);
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

Comment: It logs HTMLString correctly. The snippet provided in the question also returns correct HTMLString but it throws an error. I'm trying to add ~thousand of markers to the map and every marker has a custom icon made using ```renderToString``` which throws this error.

Comment: Your sandbox does not contain any code relevant to your question

Comment: Ouch, sorry, it should work now.

Comment: L.icon seems to not have the functionality that your looking for. You must pass in a URL and not HTML. 
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-option

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. I meant L.DivIcon, not L.Icon. I updated the question and added link to Leaflet docs.

Answer (score -2):

I used `renderToStaticMarkup` to render a custom marker. Marker is getting rendered but still getting the warnings.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";
import { divIcon } from "leaflet";
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: -0.091,
    zoom: 13
  };

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    const iconMarkup = renderToStaticMarkup(
      <Fab size="small" variant="extended">
        Test
      </Fab>
    );
    const customMarkerIcon = divIcon({
      html: iconMarkup
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={position} icon={customMarkerIcon}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-icon-material-mx1iu